# Is vertical text-overflow possible with css3?

Tags: css

to add ellipsis to a sentence that is too long you can use this method:
http://jsfiddle.net/ArKeu/

that works great for widths but is it somehow possible to add ellipsis vertically too?
that doesn't seem to work :(

http://jsfiddle.net/ArKeu/2/

does anyone know this, Thanks.

Comment: What would your desired result look like?

Comment: basically it cuts the text after 300 vertical pixels and adds ellipsis. Like in the first jsfiddle

Comment: But then, would the ellipsis fall outside of the parent element?

Comment: well that's not the plan, that's why i'm asking :p

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Currently there is no cross-browser CSS-only way to achieve such behavior.

You can do this now only in webkit-based browsers by using the `-webkit-box` and `-webkit-line-clamp`, see http://jsfiddle.net/ArKeu/7/

The css rule boils down to:

```css
your-css-selector {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Where the number value for `-webkit-line-clamp` is the maximal number of lines you want to be displayed.

Comment: Nowadays, I think we can consider `line-clamp` is a cross-browser CSS only solution, although it remains `-webkit` prefixed. See [can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_-webkit-line-clamp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp).

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` is unnecessary. `-webkit-line-clamp` adds an ellipsis by itself.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE! UPDATE! UPDATE!**

Since the time when I wrote that answer, [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) seems to have cooled-off and died. The project still exists on github so you can check it out.

But, there is a better alternative here: [ftellipsis](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftellipsis). It is cross-browser.

---

Why should webkit browsers have all the fun?

This solution here is much more extensive, and provides support for other browsers as well.
<del>http://reusablebits.com/post/2642059628/introducing-clamp-js</del> (dead link)

Comment: That link is dead, can you provide an alternate?

Comment: For what it's worth, ftellipsis doesn't seem to active either anymore (last commit August 2014).

Answer (score 6):

[**CSS Overflow Module Level 4**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2023/WD-css-overflow-4-20230321/) is a W3C specification which, as of 2023-05-08, is in Working Draft state.

It defines a CSS property called [`line-clamp`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-4/#line-clamp) which accomplishes your goals. It is based on the earlier Webkit property, mentioned in kizu's answer; and as such, the evolving specification continues to be available in [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-line-clamp) with the `-webkit-` prefix.

I will update this answer as the CSS Overflow Module Level 4 specification advances.