# Trouble with text-overflow: ellipses in a specific height paragraph

Tags: html, css

For example I have a paragraph with specific height. I want everything that over that height becomes ellipses (...) instead of cutting the sentence into half like in the picture:
[image]

I've tried using **text-overflow: ellipses** but it was no use.
Please help me with this one. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is vertical text-overflow possible with css3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004006/is-vertical-text-overflow-possible-with-css3)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```css
div{display:block;width:300px;text-overflow:ellipsis;;overflow-y:scroll;max-height:200px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div>this is text this is text this is textthis is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text</div>
```