# split html text by some special tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have description with html format. But it need to display in one line. And at the end of line, we need to display '...' when it's too long. I tried to use css, some thing like :

> overflow: hidden;   text-overflow: ellipsis;   white-space: nowrap;

It worked. but when I put some html tags such as p, div. It can not work any more. It displayed more than one line :(.
I tried to use javascript also, split html text by regex pattern, I used this pattern /</?[^>]+>/g, but it also remove some tags: b..., but I don't want it. i just want to remove div, br, p, table...
So could you give me some idea. Thanks.

Comment: This question is not well formed. Show us your code which is not doing what you want please, and state what you were expecting instead to happen.

Comment: I have a hml text: {code}<div>Khoai lang <b> ngon </b>nhat </div> the gioi <div class="">dang o day ne. Mai do Mai do {code}. And I want to display Khoai lang ngon nhat. In this case, I delete some div tag and keep b tag. Can you understand me?

Comment: div and p tags are block elements(please check it out) they insert the text as a new line. so vertically we cant apply ellipsis (its possible but not with support for all browsers), please use a javascript library for this, checkout [ftellipsis](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftellipsis), stackoverflow question reference: [vertical-ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004006/is-vertical-text-overflow-possible-with-css3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try split join:

```
"some text <br />".split("<br />").join("");
```

if you have variable tags you may should try something like this:

```
var tagString = "someText<div class='someClass'><b><h1>someText<h1><br /></b></div>";
var noTagString = "";
var lastIndex = 0;
var dontRemove = ["<b>", "</b>"];
// iterate over the tagged text
for(var i = 0; i < tagString.length; i++){
   // check for '>'
   if(tagString[i] === "<"){
      // if '<' is found
      noTagString += tagString.substring(lastIndex, i);
      // take the left over
      var leftOver = tagString.substr(i, tagString.length);
      var goOn = false;
      // check for tags to keep
      for(var k = 0; k < dontRemove.length; k++){
         if(leftOver.startsWith(dontRemove[k])){
            goOn = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (goOn){
         // we found a tag we want to keep so go on
         continue;
      }
      // iterate over the left over
      for(var j = 0; j < leftOver.length; j++){
         // if closing tag is found
         if(leftOver[j] === ">"){
            // update i and last index
            i = i + j;
            lastIndex = i + 1;
            break;
         }
       }
    }
 }
```

this is not tested to well but maybe it points you in the right direction.
Put the tags you want to keep in the dontRemove array.

Comment: In html we have some tags make new line: br|p|div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|nav|ul|ui|div|tr|address|article|aside|blockquote|dd|dir|dl|dt|fieldset|figcaption|figure|footer|hgroup|hr|legend|menu|ol|optgroup|option|pre|section|table and we need to split them by pattern. But we have start tag and end tag. And in these tag we can write some thing like class="abc". So I think that, we should find you pattern for these tags. :(

Comment: Would you mind set this as accepted answer if it helps or tell what's not working?