# Replace hidden overflow with "..."

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, hidden

In **javscript** i created a function that puts text in a div. However, sometimes this text is too long for this div. So in **css** I set overflow to hidden.

```
overflow: hidden
```

I don't just want to not show this overflow, but i want to replace it with "..." in order that the user sees that the information is not complete.

I've already tried to count the length of the string, and stop it after a few characters, but as my div is really narrow, it doenst seem like a good solution.

How could i do this?

EDIT: i want to have mutiple lines, not one

HTML:

```
<div id="event">This is way too much text for this div, but i want to show it partly</div>
```

CSS:

```
#event{
   position: fixed; //doensn't have to do anything with the problem
   font-size: 8px; //idem
   width: 50px;
   line-height: 1em;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Let's say the div can display this text:

This is way too
much text for
this div, but

How can i add 3 dots after 'but' ?

Comment: use [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: It depends if the text is on one line or multiline? If it's multiline you can't use `text-overflow: ellipsis; `

Comment: on what event or action do you want your 3 dots to go away.  What does it look like in an action sequence for a user to read all of the text?

Comment: The text is on multiple lines. If i use text-overflow: ellipsis, i only get one line of text...

Comment: can you send an example of the `html` you have please, it could help us understand the problem a little better.

Comment: I think you should post your html/css so far.

Comment: Okay! See post.

Comment: I found it [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033508/10153945) unfortunatly it seem only firefox doesn't support it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a javascript function called `hideOverflow` which automatically hides the overflow and replaces it with an ellipsis.

```js
function hideOverflow(element) {

  //Calculate lineHeight and maxLineCount for parent's height
  element.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  var maxLineCount = Math.floor(parent.clientHeight / element.clientHeight);
  var maxLineHeight = element.clientHeight * maxLineCount;
  element.style.whiteSpace = 'normal';

  //Find and set maxLineHeight by replacing the overflow with an ellipses
  if (element.clientHeight > maxLineHeight) {
    var max = maxLineCount * element.style.lineHeight;
    for (var i = 0; element.clientHeight > maxLineHeight; i++) {
      element.innerHTML = element.textContent.slice(0, -2) + '&hellip;';
      i++;
      if (i === max) break;
    }
  }
}

hideOverflow(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

```css
div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border: 1px black solid;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean et magna at sem tristique lobortis quis et nulla. Sed porttitor massa ac efficitur viverra. Donec eu commodo justo. Suspendisse libero quam, tincidunt non faucibus et, vehicula vel orci. Praesent in enim at odio ullamcorper gravida nec auctor diam. Aenean et feugiat quam. Donec sem felis, tristique et euismod at, elementum eget nulla.</p>
</div>
```

This does not support margin or padding currently, but you could easily adjust the `Calculate lineHeight and maxLineCount for parent's height` section of the `hideOverflow` function in order to achieve this same result with padding and margin.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

The `line-clamp` property truncates text at a specific number of lines.
[Read more about line-clamp](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/).
Also: please **check the browser support**.

```css
 p#event {
  --line-height: 1.4;
  --num-lines:2; /* 2 lines of text*/
  line-height:var(--line-height);
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */  
  max-width: 150px;
  height: calc(1em * var(--line-height) * var(--num-lines)); /*2 lines*/
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: var(--num-lines);
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  The article has links to a [javascript implementation](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) for those having to support older browsers.

Comment: Nice solution.  Didn't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
p {     
 display: inline-block;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 line-height: 1.6rem;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 4; //it shows how many rows will display
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 max-height: 7.2rem;
 }
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

You should add both conditions. You can check the demo in the fiddle.

```css
p{
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div{
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p> Your text is long enough to  show this</p>
<p> Your text is long enough to  show this</p>
<p> Your text is long enough to  show this</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not solving the mulitline.

Comment: What i you have, let's say a div (100px x 200px) and just one <p>-tag?

Comment: So you have only one <p> and you want to see the text and the dots on different lines? Am i understanding you correctly?

Comment: No, i want the text on multiple lines, but only dots at the last line

Comment: I think you can not do this with css but you can do it with this js trick (case 3): http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/      Let me know if that help you.