# How to show two paragraph in a single with dots using css?

Tags: html, css

code:

```
<div id="over_flow">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>

    <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

I have a div where I have two paragraph which has dynamic content it may be too long as much as possible. Now, What am I doing here I want to show my data with `dots(...)` after two or three line but now it not looking so good. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You will need JavaScript for that

Comment: what javascript @JackBashford

Comment: Here's a plugin that can be used for multiple lines https://codepen.io/sair/pen/KpbeKp

Comment: You may find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967953/replace-hidden-overflow-with/51969160#51969160#51969160#51969160

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Single line you can try this following code

```css
#over_flow p {
      white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="over_flow">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>

    <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

For 2 or 3 lines have following code

To Change the number of lines change `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;` attribute

```css
#over_flow p {  
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 20px;    

    /*The problematic part is below*/   
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: normal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div id="over_flow">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>

    <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```